# Using strictly algebra, how to calculate the direction of the adjacent angle, and as well the direction of the angle to the hypotenuse.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

First question, here goes!

In respect to, [How to calculate opposite direction angle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1319615/how-to-calculate-opposite-direction-angle)

I am currently trying to find a ***non*** Taylor-series/***non*** calculator method to calculate (in degrees) sine, cosine and tangent-- quickly and efficiently by hand.

So far, I have only tried experimenting with an algebraic formula I happened to make, that attempts at finding the sine of a degree angle to the ten-thousandths place.

For example, "Find the Sine of 60 degrees"

I tried conjuring up a draft of a formula, but I have the slightest clue on how to find the adjacent angle algebraically;

deg. = degrees

n = math.sign of 180;

meaning, ***if "n" is greater than or equal to a 180th degree, then "n" = -1.
 else if  "n" is less than or equal to a 180th degree,  then`"n" = 1.***

(I say "180th degree"  instead of "180 degrees" in case the angle plugged into the formula below is equal or greater than 360 degrees or below zero degrees)* , then n = -1.***

If sine = opposite/adjacent and
opposite =(deg. + (180 * n)) then

sine = (deg. + (180 * n))/adjacent

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Some other postulates

Hypotenuse = adjacent/cosine

Adjacent = opposite/tangent

Comment: Huh????????????

Comment: I don't think I worded the definition of n correctly, I write in lua and I have a hard time trying to communicate this concept, so I can understand,  how my question is worded funny. I meant to say,                                                       
"if n => 180 then n must = -1.                                                                           
 if n < 180 then must equal 1."